# Common origin of PIE feminine and collective plural and semantic implications

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, gender

It is generally believed that the neuter nominative-accusative plural and feminine singular in PIE both originate in a common **-h<sub>2</sub>* suffix which originally marked collective, although [recent works](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/42987679/Feminine_gender_in_Bubenik__John_Hewson__Sarah_Rose__-libre.pdf?1456259597=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DThe_origin_of_the_feminine_gender_in_Ind.pdf&Expires=1670632048&Signature=PMorsUY2UMjzvGwTiB5NXJtdqYEcFiJXU-rLoXdYMdU867Bk85%7EMhxhAtFZfXbvwCGuUH5TtFOHkLPSdPM3CAwZP16EUrELdxCT8de4ebeJjgSDBX58XFycX0h93vYv8MO1CagoRgVoI-HJzoAUB4-VUpLZiLS3XB-KKUyILSRpa7f8d%7E817rf%7EXZVfhk%7EVnh%7EqZdSQMjRUQaynQ6l8wK0QUlKgz2YjfK9xVwy92xFr1yhEFjRxedjkRxK14dU4XKhoASW3vMOenNEHQFPkN7hzE5jjfDM-4DaDIFSFE61dCWcnoeBcr-6UJMzJURSwHh4DyDxHKUXgB5Rh-nwlRBQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA) tend to indicate that this suffix was rather a derivational suffix used to derive abstract nouns, which later developed into a plural inflectional ending on one hand, and a marker of the feminine inflectional class on the other hand in separate ways.

Have there been any works or claims about the semantic or anthropological implications of this fact - including, I suppose, highly controversial ones - assuming that the hypothesis of a collective marker later evolving into a gender marker is correct ?

(I understand this is not strictly speaking a question about historical linguistics, so I hope it is relevant)

Comment: Well sorry for the misunderstanding, but summing up the content of the linked paper is pretty much what I did in the sentence following the link. Besides, the content of the work itself is of little relevance to my question, I mentioned it out of fairness because it is at odds with the assumption that PIE feminine gender developed from collective. What I'm interested in are potential other works elaborating upon this very assumption. Should I edit my question to make it clearer ?

Comment: The paper has a few citations and the author published again in 2014 with Neri and Roland Schuhmann (eds.), Studies on
the Collective and Feminine in Indo-European: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=15687203215086519659&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=de but Yates and Lundquist's morphology does not seem to expound on it, though it's in the bibliography. I really need to read that.

Comment: Not an answer but it is interesting that Middle Egyptian, an afro-asiatic language and language of the hieroglyphs that has two genders, also uses the 'feminine' gender for both females and abstract concepts.

Comment: @Ned this is a common Afroasiatic trait, clearly seen in the modern Semitic languages as well